# Form Creation for use in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, data-collection, environmental-monitoring

I am using ArcMap 10.2.

I am trying to create a form to use in the field (on a construction site).  This form will be used to inspect features such as a inlet.  My main goal is to have the information collected in the field by way of a cell phone be easily inputted back into GIS.

Comment: As it stands you are telling us what you want to do but not what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Please unhold this as someone has allready answered my question!

Comment: I agree as well, way too many questions put on hold for marginal reasons lately.

Comment: Any question that does not say what you want to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck is likely to attract votes for it to be placed on hold so that it can be improved to that much more answerable state.  It then goes into the review queue where it can attract re-open votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to look at in this case is Survey 123 ,  it is free if you are already using ESRI Arc products, it allows you to create Forms that you have users fill out and that pushes the data back to your feature class.

https://survey123.arcgis.com/

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/182705-survey123-for-arcgis-used-in-utilities

https://www.esri.com/~/media/Files/Pdfs/library/casestudies/survey123-amwc.pdf

http://sspinnovations.com/blog/2016/07/26/survey123-data-collection-alternative-gas-utilities#.WE7ZDbIrKCg

alternatively you can use ESRI Collector to build roughly the same thing using popup windows, but in your case I think survey 123 is more appropriate.